# what is relation between masksToBounds and cornerRadius?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, calayer, cornerradius

My scroll has some views that is `cornerRadius = 10.0` and `masksToBounds = YES`.

This causes a performance issue for scrolling my scroll view. Though I tried each view's `shouldRasterize` is set `YES`, the issue is not solved.

However, I know the solution for this issue. That is what `masksToBound` is set `NO`. (`masksToBound's` default value is NO)
Although `masksToBound` is `NO`, my views's corners still have curve and the performance issue is solved, too.

I want to know about relation between `cornerRadius` and `masksToBounds`. I'm afraid of unexpected issues with this setting.

Thank you.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

After providing `cornerRadius` which specifies a radius used to draw the rounded corners of the receiver’s background.

Now it depends on `masksToBounds` which determines if the sublayers are clipped to the receiver’s bounds. So if it is set to `YES`, an implicit mask matching the layer bounds is applied to the layer, including the effects of the `cornerRadius` property. If it is set to `YES` and a mask property is specified, the two masks are multiplied to get the actual mask values.

For example:

If you set that on a `CALayer` with image contents, the image will still be drawn outside the corner radius boundary. You can solve this by setting `sublayer.masksToBounds` to `YES`; but if you do that, the shadows won’t show up because they’ll be masked out!

Answer (score -2):

There is not any specific relation ship .. actually when you call the Corner Radius it will crop the view at what radius you have passed and MaskToBound:Yes make it transparent to that part which you have cropped else it would be visible...