# Corner Radius property of UILabel is not working in iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7.1

I am setting the `cornerRadius` property for `UILabel`. Its working fine all version of `iOS < 7.1`. Following code i have used,

```
UILabel *originaltagLbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(startX, startY, 100,30)];    
[originaltagLbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MuseoSans-500" size:15]];
[originaltagLbl setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[originaltagLbl setTextColor:UIColorFromRGB(0xffffff)];
originaltagLbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
originaltagLbl.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
originaltagLbl.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
originaltagLbl.layer.borderWidth = 1;
[scrollView addSubview:originaltagLbl];
```

if i use this, just simply displaying the label as rectanglular box, So how to set the corner radius of `UILabel` in `iOS 7.1`

Comment: Are you sure your label has the `.clipsToBounds` property set to YES?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Add the next line to your code:

```
// Swift:
originaltagLbl.layer.masksToBounds = true

// Objective C:
originaltagLbl.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

For information see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11325605/2298998) SO answer, or read [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/masksToBounds).

Comment: Interesting. This works, but why did it change? I've never had to use layer.masksToBounds on UILabels for cornerRadius before.

Comment: @AndrewRobinson I added to answer some sources where is explained how it works.

Comment: I understand how it works, I'm wondering when/why it changed. I have been using cornerRadius on UILabels forever and haven't had to use masksToBounds.

Comment: thank you so much for this. I have been searching this for so long

Answer (score 9):

Swift 3/4/5

```
    yourlabel.layer.cornerRadius = 8 //your desire radius
    yourlabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the UILabel's `clipsToBounds` property to YES

Answer (score 1):

It's true that clipsToBounds works in 7.1, but the problem is in situations where you're scrolling/animating it's really slow and makes everything laggy.

Setting the background color on the layer instead of the uiview is all that is needed.

See:
[UILabel layer cornerRadius negatively impacting performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735623/uilabel-layer-cornerradius-negatively-impacting-performance/6254531#6254531)

Answer (score 1):

Swift 2 solution :

```js
@IBOutlet weak var your_label: UILabel!

your_label.layer.cornerRadius = 5
your_label.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code,

```
[[myLabel layer] setCornerRadius:5.0f];
[[myLabel layer] setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

thanks,